# Using Regex in a SQL Select

Tags: sql, json, regex, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL column that contains JSON payloads.  I'm writing a SQL query that will extract part of that column w/ regex.

In the following field:

```json
{
   "myContent":{
      "fieldG":null,
      "valuable":"this is the text",
      "fieldH":[
         "a4a6ba1c2e0e4a9c89dac46f1092b505"
      ],
      "fieldI":"1"
   },
   "fieldJ":"1441375349399"
}
```

I want to scrape the string immediately after "valuable":

I was experimenting w/ something like this:

```
\"valuable\":\".*\"
```

... but that doesn't help.  For starters, I only want what's AFTER valuable and colon.  Also, that particular regex matches from "valuable:" all the way through the entire end of the line.  That's way more text than I need.

Comment: MS SQL Server does not support regex. You may try with `LIKE '"valuable":"%"'`, where `%` means any number of characters.

Comment: There's no RegEx in SQL Server. You can add it through CLR functions but if you are planning to go that route, may as well parse the JSON properly in a .NET language. Treating JSON as string gets hairy quickly with spaces, line breaks, escapes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2016 CTP3 you could use JSON_VALUE function, e.g.:
SELECT JSON_VALUE(column, '$.mycontent.valuable').
See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jocapc/archive/2015/05/16/json-support-in-sql-server-2016.aspx

If you cannot wait for Sql Server 2016, you can use some JSON CLR library e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000953/JSON-for-SQL-Server-Part
Otherwise yo would need to use PATINDEX and substring.